# Google Analytics event firing even when there are validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, google-analytics

all!

I have built a WordPress website that has a contact form. I have added a javascript code to track form submission events.

The problem is that the Google Analytics event is firing even when there are validation errors and the form is not submitted. Validation and submission are done by the form plugin (it is a form that is connected to an MS Dynamics CRM).

```
jQuery('div#main_form form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit');
    var form = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ form.submit()}, 150);
  });
```

Also, this code is causing the page to reload when you hit the submit button (even when there are validation errors).

Can you please help me with this code so that the event doesn't fire unless the form is submitted? My knowledge of JavaScript / jQuery is very limited, please be very specific.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What form plugin? In what point is the validation occurring?

Comment: Form submission should happen only after the validation is successfully completed. Which means `jQuery('div#main_form form').submit(function(e)` method should not be executed if the validation fails. Also, I think it is not necessary to have form submission inside settimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed the issue:

```
jQuery('div#main_form form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!jQuery('div#main_form form').valid()) return;
    ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit');
    var form = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ form.submit()}, 150);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely plugin-specific behaviour. There is definitely all the validation happens after the visitor 'submits' the form so listening to 'submit' event won't help you. 
Two common ways to handling this are 1) performing the same validation as the plugin does before sending GA event 2) there may be some JS hooks provided by a plugin like `ajaxsuccess` or `wpcf7:mailsent` events so you could add a listener to that events.
But these are definitely beyond the 'limited knowledge of JavaScript' so I suggest you to look for a real developer's help